# Alternative to numpy.random.binomial that allows 64 bits or more?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random

I need to randomly generate a series of numbers according to the binomial distribution. Numpy's random suite provides a means to do this, but unfortunately it seems to be limited to handling 32-bit numbers for the value of *n* and I want to work with values outside that range. 64-bits should suffice, although arbitrarily higher precision would work just as well.

Example output:

```
>>> np.random.binomial(1<<40, 0.5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 3506, in mtrand.RandomState.binomial (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:16555)
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Is there an alternative I could use? Or a means to get numpy to use 64-bit numbers internally in this random generator?

Or do I need to saddle up and roll my own?

(As pointed out by Robert Klein, numpy does do 64-bit on 64-bit platforms except Windows; unfortunately I'm using Windows).

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more? `np.random.binomial( np.iinfo(np.int64).max , 0.5)` works just fine on my laptop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On machines where a C `long` integer is 64-bit, `numpy.random.binomial()` will accept and generate 64-bit integers. Most 64-bit platforms except for Windows are such. For example, on my 64-bit OS X machine:

```
[~]
|11> np.random.binomial(1 << 40, 0.5)
549755265539

[~]
|12> np.random.binomial(1 << 40, 0.5) > (1<<32)
True
```

Alternately, if you are stuck on Windows, consider using the [Normal Approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation) to the binomial distribution. At such large `n`, the approximation should be excellent.

```
def approx_binomial(n, p, size=None):
    gaussian = np.random.normal(n*p, sqrt(n*p*(1-p)), size=size)
    # Add the continuity correction to sample at the midpoint of each integral bin.
    gaussian += 0.5
    if size is not None:
        binomial = gaussian.astype(np.int64)
    else:
        # scalar
        binomial = int(gaussian)
    return binomial
```

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately I'm using Windows so it doesn't help much.

Comment: Consider using the [Normal Approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation) to the binomial distribution. It probably has better behavior at such large `n` anyways. `np.random.normal(n*p, np.sqrt(n*p*(1-p))).astype(np.int64)`

Comment: Could you post that as an answer so I can accept it, please?

Comment: Added it to this answer. Thanks!

Comment: I added a continuity correction and found that I need to cast to int in the normal fashion rather than using `.astype` but otherwise that worked excellently. Thanks, Robert.

Comment: Ah, right. `astype()` is just when generating an array instead of a single value. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

There is an exact and efficient sampler to generate binomial(*n*, 1/2) random variates, even if *n* is large, described in Bringmann et al. 2014. An algorithm that is equivalent to the one described in that paper is as follows:

1. If *n* is less than 4, generate *n* unbiased random bits (zeros or ones) and return their sum. Otherwise, if *n* is odd, set *ret* to the result of this algorithm with *n* = *n* − 1, then add an unbiased random bit's value to *ret*, then return *ret*.
2. Set *m* to floor(sqrt(*n*)) + 1.
3. (First, sample from an envelope of the binomial curve.) Generate unbiased random bits (zeros or ones) until a zero is generated this way. Set *k* to the number of ones generated this way.
4. Set *s* to an integer in [0, *m*) chosen uniformly at random, then set *i* to *k***m* + *s*.
5. Set *ret* to either *n*/2+*i* or *n*/2 − *i* − 1 with equal probability.
6. (Second, accept or reject *ret*.) If *ret* < 0 or *ret* > *n*, go to step 3.
7. With probability choose(*n*, *ret*)**m**2<sup>*k* − *n* − 2</sup>, return *ret*. Otherwise, go to step 3. (Here, choose(*n*, *k*) is a binomial coefficient. The Python code below calculates the logarithm of this probability.)

(Note that the Bringmann paper's algorithm is more involved than this, in part to avoid rounding errors due to limited precision, and that Farach-Colton and Tsai [2015] showed how the problem of sampling binomial(*n*, *p*) random variates for any *p* can be reduced to the problem of sampling binomial(*n*, 1/2) variates. For more details, see those papers or my note "[On a Binomial Sampler](https://peteroupc.github.io/randmisc.html)".)

The following is a pure Python implementation of the binomial(1/2) algorithm that doesn't rely on 32-bit/64-bit support of the underlying operating system.

```
import random
import math

def binomhalf(n):
   if n<4: return sum(random.randint(0,1) for i in range(n))
   if n%2==1: return random.randint(0,1)+binomhalf(n-1)
   m=int(math.sqrt(n))+1
   while True:
      k=0
      while random.randint(0,1)==0: k+=1
      i=k*m+random.randint(0,m-1)
      ret=n//2+i if random.randint(0,1)==0 else n//2-i-1
      if ret<0 or ret>n: continue
      expo=-random.expovariate(1)
      p=math.lgamma(n+1)-math.lgamma(ret+1)-math.lgamma((n-ret)+1)+ \
          math.log(m)+math.log(2)*(k-n-2)
      if expo<=p: return ret
```

REFERENCES:

- K. Bringmann, F. Kuhn, et al., “Internal DLA: Efficient Simulation of a Physical Growth Model.” In: *Proc. 41st International Colloquium on Automata, Languages, and Programming (ICALP'14)*, 2014.
- Farach-Colton, M. And Tsai, M.T., 2015. Exact sublinear binomial sampling. *Algorithmica* 73(4), pp. 637-651.